# Weird (intermittent) Can't set headers after they are sent error

Tags: angularjs, express, mongoose

Have  a very strange intermittent problem, and one that I just can not understand at all. Not certain it is code related, bug in express or just me missing something.

Have an app, all in MEAN, that like so many other apps around does a bunch of API calls. Some even in parallel.

It all worked perfect this morning, actually, read the "where it gets weird", but then all of a sudden it stops working and the server starts falling over with the below error:

```
GET /api/skillList 304 45.345 ms - -
_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/ResourceEdge/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:695:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/ResourceEdge/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:232:10)
    at /Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/ResourceEdge/routes/api.js:78:9
    at /Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/ResourceEdge/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:160:11
    at Query._findOne (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/ResourceEdge/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1145:12)
    at /Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/ResourceEdge/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:156:8
    at /Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/ResourceEdge/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:18:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What I have checked.

- Threw tons of log messages, looks like it falls over at different places, or I am missing one of the places
- Spent a lot of time looking at the last call (/api/skilllist), to be working quite OK.

**Where it gets REALLY weird**

If I start the developer console in Chrome, the problem DOES NOT OCCURE, which is probably why it worked all day but then stopped working when I wanted to show it to someone...

While I was writing this, I realised that I could use safari, and it falls over with the java console on, and it is the same line server side. And its the database call below. But if I turn the console on in Chrome, it starts working... What am I missing

```
exports.canlist = function (req, res) {
        // use mongoose to get all profiles in the database
        console.log("Canlist called");
        Profile.find( {}, {'_id':1, 'alias':1, 'img':1, 'summary':1, 'keys':1}, function(err, profiles) {
            // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error " + err)
                res.send(err)
            }
            console.log("Sending back " + profiles.length + " profiles")
            res.json(profiles); // return all todos in JSON format
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after much faffing about, I figured it out. Not why it works when using java console it open on Chrome.

Basically the res.send(err) command is wrong. 
First its missing return. 
Secondly I THINK you are suppose to use the longer form like this:

```
return res.status(500).send(err);

return res.json(profile);
```

Think the problem was that it was confusing express, which probably do some pre processing, which may explain why it "seems" to blow up at all kind of times.

(Would have kept quiet about this, as it is a bit of a ridiculous mistake, but it saves someone a few hours staring at the screen I might get a christmas card this year. (or at least get to tell santa that I've been a good boy)